# How to create an array from another array where certain keys matches a value in Dataweave 2.0?

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I have the below payload from which I need to extract rows where Error[] != null and all other rows where the Id and Date match the errored row's Id and Date.

```
[
  {
    "Id": "123",
    "Date": "1/1/2021",
    "line": "ABC",
    "Error": ["Some Error 1", "Some Error 2"]
  },
  {
    "Id": "123",
    "Date": "1/1/2021",
    "line": "CDB",
    "Error": []
  },
  {
    "Id": "123",
    "Date": "2/2/2021",
    "line": "ABC",
    "Error": []
  }
]
```

From the above array, I need to get rows where

1. Error[] != null
2. Get all other rows where the Date and ID matches the object with Error != null

Desired Output here should be :

```
[
  {
    "Id": "123",
    "Date": "1/1/2021",
    "line": "ABC",
    "Error": ["Some Error 1", "Some Error 2"]
  },
  {
    "Id": "123",
    "Date": "1/1/2021",
    "line": "CDB",
    "Error": []
  }
]
```

Since **the Id and Date of 2nd Object match the first object where Error != null**, I need to get all those into one array.

How can I achieve the desired output payload? **I am able to filter out rows where Error != null, but how do I get all other rows where the Id and Date match to the errored rows?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accomplished this with two filters. First filter to find all an array of dates that pertain to errors. find all instances in the original array that have the same date and combine into array:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var data = [
  {
    "Id": "123",
    "Date": "1/1/2021",
    "line": "ABC",
    "Error": ["Some Error 1", "Some Error 2"]
  },
  {
    "Id": "123",
    "Date": "1/1/2021",
    "line": "CDB",
    "Error": []
  },
  {
    "Id": "123",
    "Date": "2/2/2021",
    "line": "ABC",
    "Error": []
  }
]
---
/*An array of dates that contain Error information with default [] to
* account for instances where no errors are present
*/
(data filter (not isEmpty($.Error))) default []
// Filter the data again to add find all objects with that Date and add to 
// an array
    reduce ((item, acc=[]) -> acc ++ (data filter (item.Date == $.Date and item.Id == $.Id)))
```

Comment: Thank you but it also needs to look at Id along with Date, where would I add ID in this?

Comment: missed the portion about the Id but have updated the code to reflect that addition

Comment: that worked just fine, Thank you. appreciate your time.

Comment: @apple123 Does this solution still work if you add another object there with id=123, date=2/2/2012 and error != null?

Comment: @Dale Yes it does and selected this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with this approach.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload groupBy ($.Id) mapObject {
  ($ groupBy ($.Date) mapObject {
      ($$):$
  })
})[0]
```

Another approach but i don't like concatenating in groupBy

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload filter ($.Error != null) groupBy ($.Id ++ "_" ++ $.Date)  mapObject {
    ($$):$
}
```

[image]

Comment: I need to look at the Error array too, so wherever the Error[] is not Blank, compare that Id and Date with other rows. How can I consider that? And there could be multiple rows with a different combinations of Id-Date which could have errors.

Comment: just a filter in there would do the trick.

Comment: I think that later one worked, let me make some changes and try. Thanks much for your time.

Comment: I tried the screenshot version that you have and it works but it gives me ALL arrays group by date/Id as key But how would I only get those groups where any one of the object's Error != null?

Comment: I tried doing `payload filterObject ((value, key, index) -> !isEmpty(value.Error))` but that doesnt seem to work, it still gives me all the key value pairs. I only want the key value pair where one of the object has error != null.

Comment: Not sure if i follow. in your original ask, you wanted all  where Error != null (filter should get you there). On top of that you want to groupBy Date and Id . GroupBy should do that for you. If the ask is any different, could you elaborate with relevant input and expected output payloads?

Comment: if you are following the screenshot , i think [0] from the fianl result would give you what you are looking for.

Comment: It is the original ask actually, let me try to explain you, the response I get from the solution above is :
`{ "date" : [{ order : 123, error : ["some error"]}, {order : 123, Error : [] }]
"date2" : [ { order : 123, Error : [] }]
}`

What I actually want is only the Date1 array since that is only one that has any array with Error != null. I want to put Date2 into different array since that doesnt have any array with Errors in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228866/discussion-between-apple123-and-salim-khan).